# Spark stateful streaming increasing memory over time

Tags: apache-spark, garbage-collection, spark-streaming

We are using spark structured streaming and aggregating the data over a period using mapGroupWithState . As the timeout occurs we are removing the state using

state.remove () .

We are using the ganglia to monitor the cluster health .
   The heap memory is keep increasing over the period.
  I am suspecting even after the state removal the old states objects are still in the memory and never cleaned . 
   What happens on to the objects on calling the state.remove () ?
  Hints are appreciated.

Comment: have the same problems a few months ago, i tried many things with no success, I think there is a memory leak or something in the state store, do you find a work around?

Comment: We enabled logging at all the levels . What we observed is state removal function triggered lazily , only when the new events occurs. Also the memory clean up was gradual.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be a comment, but I have just created my Stack Overflow account.

Few weeks ago I had the same problem with a Spark Streaming. My state was to large and I needed to drop old state. I used **mapGroupWithState** and it worked. At first I did not understand how **state.remove()** works, but I got it after a few executions.

First, when do you call the remove method? I used a timeout of a few minutes. I got how timeout and remove work when I stopped sending messages to that key after the time has expired. The events iterator was null and state.hasTimedOut was true.

So I decided do divide the function in a if.

```
if (state.hasTimedOut) {
    state.remove()
    // Here I returned my object totally null
} else {
    // deal with new event
    // update state
    // set time out
}
```

Maybe you are removing the state and not skipping the execution? Timeout will be **true** when time has expired and there are no events for the key.